# Django - Minimum time between posts

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

My models:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField(_('Content'))
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

My models is used for multi-user. So, how to set a value to handle minimum time between posts? Please give me some codes. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should sort you out: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2017/